# Is there a way to test if a variable in Go is a natural number using only the main package?

Tags: go

I am trying to detect if a variable `y` is a natural number without resorting to extra packages. Is this possible? For example, I am trying to print a message if it is a non-natural number but do not know what to put in `EXPRESSION` below. Is there a simple solution for this? Thanks.

```
package main
import "fmt"

var y = -2.3

func main() {
  if (EXPRESSION){
    fmt.Println("non-natural number!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is -2 a natural number? Is 0 a natural number? Is `int(y)!=y` good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @voker mentions, `y <= 0 || float64(int(y)) != y` should do the job.

Comment: This fails for large values of y. Float64 has larger range than int.

Answer (score 1):

Following condition should work fine

```
 1. y * -1 >= 0 
 2. y <= 0
```